# JavaScript | Как получить параметр объекта, задав путь?

Tags: javascript

Имеется объект, например:

```
var object = {
  id: 1,
  data: {
    name: "testName"
  }
}
```

Как получить `object.data.name`, имея на руках путь (`path`), записанный в `string`, то бишь: `"object.data.name"`. Но не все так просто, ведь дело в том, что мне не всегда нужно получить `object.data.name`, иногда требуется получить `object.id` и т.д., но это никак от меня не зависит.

Мне нужна альтернатива использованию подобного кода:

```
var path = "id"
var object = {
  id: 1,
  data: {
    name: "testName"
  }
}
console.log(object[path]) // 1
```

Для получения вложенных параметров, например:

```
var path = "data.name"
var object = {
  id: 1,
  data: {
    name: "testName"
  }
}
console.log(object[path]) // testName
```

Сейчас я использую:

```
var par = `['name']`
eval(`object.data${par}`)
// чтобы поменять параметр я использую
eval(`object.data${par} = "NewName"`)
```

Надеюсь, что я все понятно изъяснил и вы сможете мне помочь! Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы использовал `Object.values()`, который возвращает массив всех значений свойств объекта. Тогда, если `id` это свойство с индексом `0`, то до него можно достучаться так:

```
Object.values(obj)[0];
```

Если же мы не знаем порядок свойств в объекте, то его можно сначала приобразрвать в массив, затем в map, а уже потом вытащить значение нужного свойства, используя наш ключ:

```
let key = "id"
let map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));
map.get(key);
```

По вложенному объекту нужно будет пройтись поэтапно. То есть сначала получить сам вложенный объект, а затем уже нужное вам свойство в нем. Для этого ваш строковый путь можно прогнать через `split()`:

```
let pathArray = path.split(".");
```

И передавать в `map.get(pathArray[0])`, а затем `map.get(pathArray[1])`. Это можно делать в цикле

Comment: К сожалению, немного не подходит для моих задач! Спасибо за вариант!